# Shrink/grow image gradually when it's moved within a Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I started making a small and easy race game. It only consists of a car, a road and fuel-tanks that have to be caught by the driving car so that it doesn't run out of fuel.

The road starts at the bottom of the canvas with a width of 600px wide and at the top 10px width. I wanted to make the car-image smaller as it reaches the top and bigger when the player presses down when that the car approaches the bottom again.

Is this even possible with js? I just read this: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/make_images_grow_and_shrink_with_javascript/

but in that link they discuss it with the image being in an element, that's not my case.

Comment: You can place your create car code in a function and regenerate Car canvas on down key press with decrease in car size(width,height) of 10px.

Comment: This was my initial thought! However, I wondered if there was already a simple function out there as Canvas is pretty populair. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Mieer yep you can do this without a problem.

Basically with the canvas.drawImage function it can take in 5 parameters.

```
drawImage(imageSrc, xPosition, yPosition, imageWidth, imageHeight);
```

So what you will have to do is take the players yPosition and use that to mutate the image height.

here is a simple jsFiddle showing the drawImage 5 paremters

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/oc0cdd2c/

HTML

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="200"></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

var canvasHeight = 200;

var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTghB-IW500LgTFAq6JPuwTUJ4mLuOsVawUkbXNLa4uCB9N_wKf";

var draw = new function()
{
    //100% height
    context.drawImage(image,10,150);

    //10% height
    context.drawImage(image,10,10, image.width, (image.height / 100 * 50));
}

draw();
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you for the very detailed and useful answer!